# Best way to iterate through a Set in Java

Tags: java, loops, collections, iterator, set

The situation is that i have to iterate over a set having size up to 5000 elements in it. Currently, i am using a normal for loop with iterator.

```
for (Iterator iterator = allValues.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {

     ListMetadataElem element = (ListMetadataElem) iterator.next(); 
     NameValueObject value = new NameValueObject(); 
     value.setId(element.getListMetadataElemSeqId().toString());    
     value.setValue(element.getListMetadataElemNm());   
     abstractVO.getAllListMetadataElems().add(value);       
}
```

The issue is its taking too much time to iterate like 6-7 seconds and i have to call the same loop multiple times.

Comment: Give a chance to **Java 8 parallel stream**

Comment: Are you sure that it is the iteration that is taking the time?  5000 elements should take next to nothing

Comment: I don't use Java a lot, but in Python, I would expect iteration over a set of mere `5000` elements to be very fast, and only a minute fraction of 6-7 seconds. I can only presume it would be similary fast in Java, and probably a lot faster. I suspect it is whatever is going on in *inside your loop*, so what exactly does `abstractVO.getAllListMetadataElems()` do, for example?

Comment: On my slow PC, a set of 5000 Strings takes 324 ms

Answer (score 5):

Here are the comparisons:

```
public class IterateSet {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        //example Set
        Set<String> set = new HashSet<>();

        set.add("Jack");
        set.add("John");
        set.add("Joe");
        set.add("Josh");

        long startTime = System.nanoTime();
        long endTime = System.nanoTime();

        //using iterator
        System.out.println("Using Iterator");
        startTime = System.nanoTime();
        Iterator<String> setIterator = set.iterator();
        while(setIterator.hasNext()){
            System.out.println(setIterator.next());
        }
        endTime = System.nanoTime();
        long durationIterator = (endTime - startTime);


        //using lambda
        System.out.println("Using Lambda");
        startTime = System.nanoTime();
        set.forEach((s) -> System.out.println(s));
        endTime = System.nanoTime();
        long durationLambda = (endTime - startTime);


        //using Stream API
        System.out.println("Using Stream API");
        startTime = System.nanoTime();
        set.stream().forEach((s) -> System.out.println(s));
        endTime = System.nanoTime();
        long durationStreamAPI = (endTime - startTime);


        //using Split Iterator (not recommended)
        System.out.println("Using Split Iterator");
        startTime = System.nanoTime();
        Spliterator<String> splitIterator = set.spliterator();
        splitIterator.forEachRemaining((s) -> System.out.println(s));
        endTime = System.nanoTime();
        long durationSplitIterator = (endTime - startTime);


        //time calculations
        System.out.println("Iterator Duration:" + durationIterator);
        System.out.println("Lamda Duration:" + durationLambda);
        System.out.println("Stream API:" + durationStreamAPI);
        System.out.println("Split Iterator:"+ durationSplitIterator);
    }
}
```

The code is self explanatory.
The result of the durations are:

```
Iterator Duration:495287
Lamda Duration:50207470
Stream API:2427392
Split Iterator:567294
```

We can see the Lambda takes the longest while Iterator is the fastest.
Apart from this there is the traditional age-old enhanced for loop.

Comment: So about 0.5 seconds for an iterator and 50 seconds for Lamba - does not seem quite rigth

Comment: Haven't downvoted though, still read more about benchmarking or else just try and execute the same code multiple times to realize how incorrect those values could be in terms of setting a benchmark.

Comment: @Scary Wombat It's 1000000 nanoseconds in 1 millisecond. So the lambda is 50 milliseconds. Converter here -
 https://www.convertunits.com/from/nanoseconds/to/milliseconds

Comment: @ScaryWombat But that is what I got

Comment: @PritamBanerjee **Learn to benchmark**  At the very minimum you should run these a few times and have some kind of warm up